# SQLAlchemy - Array of multiple types without inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have an existing set of sqlalchemy models like so

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)
    email = Column(String)


user_group = Table('user_group', Base.metadata,
                   Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')),
                   Column('group_id', Integer, ForeignKey('groups.id'))
                   )


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    members = relationship("User", secondary=user_group)
```

and I would like to create a third model which can have a 1 to many relationship with either a `User` or a `Group` type. So I want to end up with something that can be used like this

```
class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contacts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type_id = Column(Integer)  # the id of the group or user row which it refers to.
    type = Column(String)  # 'group' or 'user'

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'things'
    relationship('Contact')  # Array of Contacts
```

where

```
thing = Thing()
thing.contacts[0].type # returns 'group' or 'user'
thing.contacts[0].contact  # returns the actual User or Group object
```

I know this can be done with inheritance but is there any alternative? I'd rather not have to subclass my basic User and Group models.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Read [Generic Associations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/examples.html#module-examples.generic_associations) section of the documentation.
Your description matches the case of the [`Generic ForeignKey`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/_modules/examples/generic_associations/generic_fk.html)